# What is the ruling on arousal & ghusl?

Tags: salat, sharia, women, ghusl, fatwa

I’m kind of embarrassed to ask this but I want to know: Can something that comes from inappropriate thoughts require ghusl? I get those feelings quite often everyday, I try to ignore them but then sometimes when I get the feeling it’s only there for a second and I never know if I have to do ghusl or not. I read that it depends on if we feel pleasure (then it’s maniy) or just desire (then it’s madhiy) but I don’t know which I’m feeling. As for looks, I can’t tell the difference between the discharge.

Answer (score 0):

There are three symptoms of semen(maniy) in men:
A) It is based on lust and instinctual satisfaction.
B) Come out by pushing and jumping.
C) When coming out, the body relaxes.
Therefore, any liquid that comes out of a person is not najis and does not need ghusl. But if he had those conditions, it is not me. There is a ruling on janabah and you should perform janabah ghusl.

" madhiy": is the water that arouses when you see scenes that provoke or imagine lustful scenes without jumping and without jumping. Its amount is much less than semen.

https://www.pasokhgoo.ir/node/60806

https://www.pasokhgoo.ir/node/36875